# Multiple urls in 1 url

Tags: python, url, urllib

I want to use multiple urls, but in stead of typing them all like I did below, I want to write a code that automatically +1's the last number in the url until the end of the month. Is that possible?

```
eventurl = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/1/"
eventurl2 = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/2/"
eventurl3 = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/3/"
```

Comment: Yes it is. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: This feels like you are very new to programming in general. Just as a side suggestion - have a look at loops and lists. They will go a long way in helping you handle data like this.

Comment: Yes I've never written a code before and I chose this subject for my big essay due in ten days. I found this website and figured what I could not find quickly on the Internet, I would give it a shot here and see what people commented. I'm almost done now anyway, but this is the last thing I'm still struggling with.. @Bilkokuya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something called the for loop try this code snippets

```
base_url = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/{}/"
number_of_days_in_month = 30
for i in range(number_of_days_in_month):
    print(base_url.format(i+1))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Only one thing: I want to use data from all the urls, but if I try this 

base_url = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/{}/"
number_of_days_in_month = 30
for i in range(number_of_days_in_month):
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url.format(i+1))
data = data.read().decode()
events = data.split("# bin\tvalue")
nevents = [d.split("\t")[1] for d in events[1].strip().split("\n")]
it only uses data from the last url

Answer (score 0):

This works!

```
eventurl = "http://data.hisparc.nl/show/source/eventtime/501/2017/1/"
for dag in range(1, 32): 
    print(eventurl + str(dag))
```

(dag = day in Dutch)